# Why is this not a default constructor in "Call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of 'QQmlElement'

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I'm trying to register a JB_NodeModel in the Qml Engine. 
I get this error:

"call to implicitly-deleted default constructor of QQmlElement(JB_NodeModel)  - default constructor of QQmlElement(JB_NodeModel) is implicitly deleted because base class JB_NodeModel has no default constructor."

But I can't see a problem with the default constructor. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I've used initialiser lists but doesn't seem to help.

Here is a cut down version of JB_NodeModel.h :

```
class SP3CORESHARED_EXPORT JB_NodeModel : public QAbstractItemModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
 explicit JB_NodeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr);

~JB_NodeModel();

protected:
    JB_Node* rootNode;
    JB_Node* actingRootNode;
    bool isValidURL(QString fieldName, JB_Node* node) const;

    QVector<QString> columnHeadingsV;    
    QHash<int, QVector<QString>> mapped_dbFieldNamesH;    
    QList<QString> unEditableDBFieldNamesList;
    QList<QString> editableCheckBoxDBFieldNamesList; 

private:
    JB_DatabaseManager& mDB;
    int jobID;
    int numOfLevels;
    QSharedPointer<JB_NodeModelHelpProt> nodeModelHelper;
    QVector<QSharedPointer<QHash<QString, JB_Node*>>> nodesHV;     
    QVector<JB_Node*> alteredNodesV;
    bool isTreeModel;
    bool canEmitDataChanged;

 };
```

Here is JB_NodeModel.cpp constructor source:

```
JB_NodeModel::JB_NodeModel(QObject *parent)
: QAbstractItemModel(parent),
  rootNode(nullptr),
  actingRootNode(nullptr),
  mDB(JB_DatabaseManager::instance()),
  jobID(aJobID),
  numOfLevels(1),
  nodeModelHelper(nullptr),
  isTreeModel(true),
  canEmitDataChanged(true),
  dragDropHelper(false)
{
    QSharedPointer<JB_NodeModelHelpProt> aNodeModelHelper(new JB_NodeModHelp_TreeGrpPers());
    nodeModelHelper = aNodeModelHelper;

    canEmitDataChanged = true;
    dragDropHelper = false;

    Q_ASSERT(!nodeModelHelper.isNull());

    alteredNodesV.clear();

    rootNode = nullptr;
    actingRootNode = nullptr;
```

etc.

And here is registering in QML engine:

```
QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

qmlRegisterType<JB_NodeModel>("JB_NodeModel", 1, 0, "JB_NodeModel");


QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                 &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
    if (!obj && url == objUrl)
        QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
}, Qt::QueuedConnection);
engine.load(url);
```

And here is the relevant part of qqmlprivate.h surrounding QQmlElement:

```
class QJSEngine;
class QQmlEngine;
class QQmlCustomParser;
namespace QQmlPrivate
{
    void Q_QML_EXPORT qdeclarativeelement_destructor(QObject *);
    template<typename T>
    class QQmlElement final : public T
{
public:
    ~QQmlElement() override {
        QQmlPrivate::qdeclarativeelement_destructor(this);
    }
    static void operator delete(void *ptr) {
        // We allocate memory from this class in QQmlType::create
        // along with some additional memory.
        // So we override the operator delete in order to avoid the
        // sized operator delete to be called with a different size than
        // the size that was allocated.
        ::operator delete (ptr);
    }
    static void operator delete(void *, void *) {
        // Deliberately empty placement delete operator.
        // Silences MSVC warning C4291: no matching operator delete found
    }
};


template<typename T>
```

// Error occurs on next line

```
void createInto(void *memory) { new (memory) QQmlElement<T>; }

template<typename T>
QObject *createParent(QObject *p) { return new T(p); }
```

Comment: It's a bit hard to tell, since you've only provided partial information.    Read up on providing a [mcve].    Your constructor needs to be implicit.   You have made it `explicit`.

Comment: @Sami - it takes 2 arguments, but both have default values. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Peter - why does it need to be implicit? - I've seen examples where it is explicit.

Comment: @Peter - I've added more to the .h file.

Comment: I notice that the error message centers around `QQmlElement`, yet that class does not appear in your code. This is potentially a huge obstacle to getting a useful answer. Ideally, you should show us a [mcve]. Show us everything needed to get the compile error, but nothing more. (E.g. remove all the members of `JB_NodeModel` if you can do so while keeping the compile error.) Getting everything in one file -- no custom header file -- would be good.

Comment: @JaMiT - QQmlElement is part of QtQml.framework/Headers/qqmlprivate.h - I've added the relevant part above.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly defining your constructor. What if you do not pass any parameters to your constructor? which constructor should be used? The one which [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) is providing with a single `QObject*` argument or the one which you are defining with two arguments? You can not instantiate `JB_NodeModel` without any arguments cause your compiler cannot decide which of your constructors is the default one. In other words, calling `new JB_NodeModel()` will be **ambiguous** thus your class won't have a default constructor.

Try to make `aJobID` non-defaulted and see if it works. You can also create your constructor like this if you have to default the jobID=3:

```
explicit JB_NodeModel:JB_NodeModel(QObject *parent = nullptr):
QAbstractItemModel(parent),
jobID(3)
... 
{
 ...
}
```

A very strange thing about it is how did you successfully compile this code? I assume that you are pruning your code to include it here but to make it clear for future readers:

[QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) is an abstract class and you have to at the very least implement pure virtual functions of it. As per Qt documentation [about subclassing QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#subclassing):

> When subclassing QAbstractItemModel, at the very least you must
>   implement index(), parent(), rowCount(), columnCount(), and data().
>   These functions are used in all read-only models, and form the basis
>   of editable models.

Comment: I took jobID out of constructor as you suggested (and as updated code above shows) but still get the error. Yes I did implement the virtual functions you mentioned but did not include them as there is A LOT of code.

Comment: ok. it would be good if you can create an example withvery minimal class which reproduces the same problem and put it here.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. Turns out the default constructor was fine. Just to try it, I tried to create the JB_Node on the stack and got an error saying the constructor had int jobid in it (which I had taken out). Turns out my .pro file had been corrupted and the project was using a JB_NodeModel file from a completely different location (instead of the one that was open in Qt Creator)- not sure how this can happen but once I fixed the project, all was fine and the class registered in QML Engine ok. Now I can't get the model data to show up in the TreeView so If I can't work it out, I'll post it. Thanks to those who answered.